# How do I move the UIView to the "bottom" so that the next UIView displays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to "remove" a UIView from a superview and add it again at the end... but at the "bottom" of the rest of the UIviews that belong to the superview.

Is this possible?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmmm...

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

Might be what you're after?  Alternatively -

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
```

Though you could avoid removing the view all together (if you don't need to for any other reason) by calling sendSubviewToBack: -

```
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! - (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view; was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you mean by bottom.
You can use: `[view removeFromSuperview];` to remove it ( make sure you `retain` it ( `[view retain];` ) before you do that and `release` `[view release];` when it's no longer needed.

Another thing you can do if you want one view to be behind another view is to set its "`zPosition`" ( `view.layer.zPosition = X;` )

if a View has a `zPosition` that is bigger than another views `zPosition` it will appear on top of the other view.